# How to speed up Shamir secret share generation?

Tags: secret-sharing

Let us say we have to generate Shamir's secret share for n data points. Is there a way to speed up the implementation apart from using Horner's rule for the polynomial evaluation?

Comment: Parallelization and vectorization should also be possible if you want to invest enough effort (with parallelization probably being easier thanks to the parallel nature of this task).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the typical set up where the shares are $f(1), f(2),\ldots f(n)$ where $f(x)=c_kx^k+\cdots+c_0$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then you can use the [calculus of finite differences](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/16-1/brousseau.pdf). Skipping the initialisation step for the moment

```
for j=1,...,n 
    update f = (f + Deltaf[1]) mod p
    for i=1,..., k-1 
        update Deltaf[i] = (Deltaf[i] + Deltaf[i+1]) mod p
    output the variable f as f(j)
END
```

The main loop takes $kn$ additions and an increment (you can save $O(k^2)$ additions if you're feeling really stingy) which is very efficient.

The initial value of $f$ is $f(0)$. The initial values of $\Delta^if$ are a bit messy: $\Delta^if(0)=i!\sum_{j=i}^kc_jS(j,i)$ where $S(j,i)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Alternatively you can evaluate the first $k$ terms of $f$ and directly compute the iterated differences to compute the next $n-k$.